# Batch file Reading from a text file with system variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that read a text file containing a specific line that I want to pass as a variable.  Here is my code:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (c:\temp\fred.txt) do (

if "%%G"=="FRED" (set %%G=%%H)

)

set FRED=%FRED%

echo %FRED%

set FRED=%USERNAME%

echo %FRED%

pause
```

The content of the FRED.txt is:

```
ERIC=PATATE
FRED=%USERNAME%
```

When I run this I get:

```
C:\TEMP>SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

C:\TEMP>for /F "delims== tokens=1,2" %G in (c:\temp\fred.txt) do (if "%G" == 
"FRED" (set %G=%H ) )

C:\TEMP>(if "ERIC" == "FRED" (set ERIC=PATATE ) )

C:\TEMP>(if "FRED" == "FRED" (set FRED=%USERNAME% ) )

C:\TEMP>set FRED=%USERNAME%

C:\TEMP>echo %USERNAME%
%USERNAME%

C:\TEMP>set FRED=fred

C:\TEMP>echo fred
fred

C:\TEMP>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So when I do my for loop i'm getting the %USERNAME% and not the fred like the regular set FRED=%USERNAME% should give me.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your results are what I'd expect. Please be explicit about your expectations and tell us what `username` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another level of parsing to evaluate `%username%` - as you do it, it just reads the literal string `%username%` from the file. You can do it for example with a `call`

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (t.txt) do (
  if "%%G"=="FRED" (call set %%G=%%H)
)
set FRED=%FRED%
echo %FRED%
set FRED=%USERNAME%
echo %FRED%
pause
```